# Multiple, sequential wash sales

Tags: united-states, wash-sale, rsu

Am I doing this right? For context, I get monthly RSU vests from my company which auto-sell a few days later, so almost every sale at a loss is a wash sale.

Consider the following series of transactions:

1. Acquired 1000 shares on 9/16 for $10000 and sold on 9/19 for $8000 (wash sale)
2. Acquired 1000 shares on 10/16 for $10000 and sold on 10/19 for $8000 (wash sale)
3. Acquired 1000 shares on 11/16 for $10000 and sold on 11/19 for $15000

When reporting this to IRS, is this the right way to do it?

1. Cost basis for #1 as $10000, proceeds as $8000, disallowed wash sale amount as $2000
2. Cost basis for #2 as $10000, report wrong basis on 1099 and correct it to $12000, proceeds as $8000, disallowed wash sale amount as $4000
3. Cost basis for #3 as $10000, report wrong basis on 1099 and correct it to $14000, proceeds as $15000, capital gain of $1000 (taking the $4000 disallowed loss from #2)